# Rust FFI. Casting to void pointer

Tags: rust, ffi

I've a function which has prototype as below

```
//opaque struct
struct mosquitto;

struct mosquitto *mosquitto_new(const char *id, bool clean_session, void *obj);
```

In my c code, I'm calling it as below.

```
struct mosquitto *m = mosquitto_new(buf, true, NULL);
```

Now I want to call the above API in my rust code. rust-bindgen generated the following bindings

```
pub enum Struct_mosquitto { }
pub fn mosquitto_new(id: *const ::libc::c_char, clean_session: u8, obj: *mut ::libc::c_void) -> *mut Struct_mosquitto;
```

When I'm trying to call the above API, I'm getting a mismatch at 3rd argument.

```
let s = CString::new("ravi").unwrap();
let mqtt = mosquitto::mosquitto_new(s.as_ptr(), 1, ptr::null());
```

How do I pass NULL to *mut c_void?

**BONUS QUESTION:** How to pass a rust struct to *mut c_void ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `ptr::null()` function returns a `*const T`, what you want is the [`ptr::null_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ptr/fn.null_mut.html) function, since the argument to your function is of type `*mut ::libc::c_void`.

For passing an actual value, have a look at the answer to [Working with c_void in an FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191249/working-with-c-void-in-an-ffi)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Is there a way that I could print the struct pointed by `mqtt` ? I'm getting a panic when I try this --> println!("mqtt = {:?}", *mqtt);

Comment: maybe your `mosquitto_new` function returns a NULL, or it's because you are using an empty enum as representation. An empty enum cannot be constructed, therefor Rust inserts `unreachable!()` calls before any code that does interact with empty enums. Here's a minimal example: http://is.gd/BOEDgb