# Why does casting from a reference to a c_void pointer require a double cast?

Tags: casting, rust, ffi

When working with Foreign Function Interfaces (FFIs), I regularly see a double cast from reference-to-pointer-to-struct to pointer-to-pointer-to-void.  For example, given an FFI-like function:

```
unsafe fn ffi(param: *mut *mut c_void) {}
```

The way to call this is:

```
struct foo;

let mut bar: *mut foo = ptr::null_mut();
unsafe { ffi(&mut bar as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut c_void); }
```

Removing the intermediate cast yields this error:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&mut *mut foo` as `*mut *mut winapi::ctypes::c_void` is invalid
  --> src\main.rs:36:18
   |
36 |     unsafe { ffi(&mut bar as *mut *mut c_void); }
   |
```

I tried to get the compiler to tell me what the intermediate type is by forcing it into an obviously wrong type:

```
let mut bar: *mut foo = ptr::null_mut();
let mut test: u8 = &mut bar as *mut *mut _;
```

Which resulted in this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:36:24
   |
36 |     let mut test: u8 = &mut bar as *mut *mut _;
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected u8, found *-ptr
   |
   = note: expected type `u8`
              found type `*mut *mut _`
```

But `*-ptr` doesn't seem to be an actual type that I can put in place of `_`.  Why is the intermediate `as *mut *mut _` required, and what is the inferred type?

I found this question which is related ([Working with c_void in an FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191249/working-with-c-void-in-an-ffi)) but it doesn't actually explain anything about the double cast.

Comment: Wow I answered both and completely forgot, nice. I did have this vague feeling like I had before.

Comment: I appreciate both answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have:

```
let mut bar: *mut foo = ptr::null_mut();
```

Then you take `&mut bar`, the type is `&mut *mut foo`. But you need `*mut *mut foo`, so you can simply coerce it by doing `&mut *mut foo as *mut *mut _`, where `_` is inferred as `foo` (try typing it explicitly: `*mut *mut foo`). Once you have it as a raw pointer, *then* you are able to cast to `*mut *mut c_void`.

So to recap, the double cast is necessary to first coerce from a reference to a raw pointer, *then* from a raw pointer cast to a `c_void`, because you otherwise normally can't cast straight from a reference to a raw `c_void` pointer.

Fully typed example:

```
let mut bar: *mut foo = std::ptr::null_mut();

let mut_ref: &mut *mut foo = &mut bar;

let raw_ptr: *mut *mut foo = mut_ref as *mut *mut _;

let void_cast: *mut *mut c_void = raw_ptr as *mut *mut c_void;

unsafe { ffi(void_cast); }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a13bbc66ea7e35395609f64afaf3121d&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: To cast away the outer reference, you don't need to specify the inner pointer type; `mut_ref as *mut _ as *mut *mut c_void` will work.

Comment: Yup, just being as explicit as possible, since the OP was having trouble following the types.