# Working with winapi SetClipboardData in Rust language

Tags: winapi, rust, clipboarddata

I am attempting to set data into the Windows cipboard using the winapi crate in Rust(I am new both to Rust and the win32 api).

The input for the SetClipboardData call requires a file type, and a C generic pointer, or `*mut libc::c_void` in Rust. 
( docs linked below )

In the final version, I plan to copy image files, but I failed testing with texts strings, and here is the code for it:

```
extern crate winapi;
extern crate libc;

fn main() {
    let mut test = "test\r\n";
    let test_ptr: *mut libc::c_void = &mut test as *mut _ as *mut libc::c_void;
    loop {
        if (condition)  
        {
            // let mut test = "test\r\n";  // these commented lets are refered to issue 2
            // let test_ptr: *mut libc::c_void = &mut test as *mut _ as *mut libc::c_void; 
            unsafe {winapi::um::winuser::SetClipboardData(winapi::um::winuser::CF_TEXT, test_ptr);}
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- the pointer conversion was inpired by: [Working with c_void in an FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191249/working-with-c-void-in-an-ffi)
- WinAPI docs for this call : [nf-winuser-setclipboarddata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata)
- winapi docs in rust: [fn.SetClipboardData](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/winuser/fn.SetClipboardData.html)

### Issue 1:

With the code as is, it wont error, but also wont work, and nothing goes into the clipboard.

### Issue 2:

When the pointer declaration is inside the loop, my program panics with error: `process didn't exit successfully: exit code: 0xc0000374, STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION)`.
This got me confused, since I expected my values to be in the stack, not the heap. And if I undesrtood correclty, the winapi expects the data to be in the stack.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `input for the SetClipboardData call requires ... a C generic pointer` No, the HANDLE argument must be an HGLOBAL returned by a [GlobalAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc) call with the GMEM_MOVEABLE flag. The steps in C can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#copying-information-to-the-clipboard), don't know how that translates to rust.

Comment: *"With the code as is, it wont error"* - You aren't evaluating the return value of `SetClipboardData` so there's no way for you to know, whether it succeeded or failed.

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues with the code presented. The most prominent one being, that [SetClipboardData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboarddata) expects a `HANDLE` to memory allocated using [GlocalAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globalalloc). It's also a strict requirement to call [OpenClipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard) prior to performing operations on it.

A more subtle issue is the character encoding requirement for use with [CF_TEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats). This clipboard format expects text encoded using ANSI (codepage) encoding. Since Rust uses Unicode throughout internally, it's probably best to use `CF_UNICODETEXT` instead, and convert to UTF-16.

The following is a rough implementation:

```
[dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3.8", features = ["winuser", "winbase"] }
```

```rust
use std::ptr;
use winapi::um::winbase::{GlobalAlloc, GlobalFree, GlobalLock, GlobalUnlock, GMEM_MOVEABLE};
use winapi::um::winuser::{CloseClipboard, OpenClipboard, SetClipboardData, CF_UNICODETEXT};

fn copy_to_clipboard(text: &str) {
    // Needs to be UTF-16 encoded
    let mut text_utf16: Vec<u16> = text.encode_utf16().collect();
    // And zero-terminated before passing it into `SetClipboardData`
    text_utf16.push(0);
    // Allocate memory
    let hglob =
        unsafe { GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, text_utf16.len() * std::mem::size_of::<u16>()) };
    // Retrieve writeable pointer to memory
    let dst = unsafe { GlobalLock(hglob) };
    // Copy data
    unsafe { ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(text_utf16.as_ptr(), dst as _, text_utf16.len()) };
    // Release writeable pointer
    unsafe { GlobalUnlock(hglob) };

    // Everything is set up now, let's open the clipboard
    unsafe { OpenClipboard(ptr::null_mut()) };
    // And apply data
    unsafe { SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hglob) };

    // Clean up
    unsafe { GlobalFree(hglob) };
    unsafe { CloseClipboard() };
}

fn main() {
    copy_to_clipboard("Hello, world!");
}
```

Error handling has been elided for brevity. This sample is meant to showcase how to access the clipboard using the [winapi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi). It's not production-ready code quality.

---

A safe implementation, including error handling, might look like the following. It uses the [scopeguard](https://crates.io/crates/scopeguard) crate for resource cleanup:

```
[dependencies]
winapi = { version = "0.3.8", features = ["winuser", "winbase"] }
scopeguard = "1.1.0"
```

```rust
use scopeguard::defer;
use std::io::Error;
use std::ptr;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::FALSE;
use winapi::um::winbase::{GlobalAlloc, GlobalFree, GlobalLock, GlobalUnlock, GMEM_MOVEABLE};
use winapi::um::winuser::{CloseClipboard, OpenClipboard, SetClipboardData, CF_UNICODETEXT};

fn copy_to_clipboard(text: &str) -> Result<(), Error> {
    // Needs to be UTF-16 encoded
    let mut text_utf16: Vec<u16> = text.encode_utf16().collect();
    // And zero-terminated before passing it into `SetClipboardData`
    text_utf16.push(0);
    // Allocate memory
    let hglob =
        unsafe { GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, text_utf16.len() * std::mem::size_of::<u16>()) };
    if hglob == ptr::null_mut() {
        return Err(Error::last_os_error());
    }
    // Ensure cleanup on scope exit
    defer!(unsafe { GlobalFree(hglob) };);

    // Retrieve writeable pointer to memory
    let dst = unsafe { GlobalLock(hglob) };
    if dst == ptr::null_mut() {
        return Err(Error::last_os_error());
    }
    // Copy data
    unsafe { ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(text_utf16.as_ptr(), dst as _, text_utf16.len()) };
    // Release writeable pointer
    unsafe { GlobalUnlock(hglob) };

    // Everything is set up now, let's open the clipboard
    let success = unsafe { OpenClipboard(ptr::null_mut()) } != FALSE;
    if !success {
        return Err(Error::last_os_error());
    }
    // Ensure cleanup on scope exit
    defer!(unsafe { CloseClipboard() };);
    // And apply data
    let success = unsafe { SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hglob) } != ptr::null_mut();
    if !success {
        return Err(Error::last_os_error());
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    copy_to_clipboard("Hello, world!").expect("Failed to copy text to clipboard.");
}
```

Comment: wow this is such a complete answer that it takes time to digest ! Thanks !